# concatenating fields with no line break in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, concatenation

I want to concatenate couple fields into one line using expression in SSRS

`=Fields!Address1.Value & Fields!Address2.Value +" " + Fields!City.Value + " " + Fields!State.Value`

But all the fields have a line break.  It is driving me nuts.  I need to get rid of the line break.
I also tried this in my query:

```
Concat(loc.Address1, loc.Address2,loc.City, loc.State) AS FullAddress
```

Still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your expression:
This is to replace char(10) (also known as vblf line break) with empty string "".  It should get you the result.

```
Replace(Fields!Address1.Value & Fields!Address2.Value +" " + Fields!City.Value + " " + Fields!State.Value),char(10),"")
```

Comment: Just saying... char(13) alone can cause a line break as well.  That's why I always test for both 13 and 10.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have char(13) and/or char(10) in your data.

```
Replace(Replace(Concat(loc.Address1,' ',loc.Address2,' ',loc.City,', ',loc.State),char(10),''),char(13),'') AS FullAddress
```